# Scalatest implicit Equality for Containers

Tags: scala, scalatest

We define a custom`Equality[String]`:

```
implicit val upperCaseEquality = new Equality[String] {
  override def areEqual(self: String, b: Any): Boolean = b match {
    case other: String => self.toUpperCase == other.toUpperCase
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

The following code works, as expected:

```
Seq("a").view should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs Seq("A")
```

Now, we add a custom `Equality` for `Seq`:

```
implicit def SeqEquality[T, SEQ[e] <: GenSeq[e]](implicit equality: Equality[T]): Equality[SEQ[T]] = new Equality[SEQ[T]] {
  override def areEqual(self: SEQ[T], b: Any): Boolean = b match {
    case other: GenSeq[_] => self.size == other.size && self.zip(other).forall(equality.areEqual _ tupled)
    case _ => false
    }
}
```

Custom `TripleEquals` equality works for `Seq`:

```
assert(Seq("a") === Seq("A"))
```

but does not work for `SeqView`:

```
assert(Seq("a").view === Seq("A"))

Exception in thread "main" org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: SeqView("a") did not equal List("A")
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [what `.view` returns](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Seq@view(from:Int,until:Int):scala.collection.SeqView[A,Repr]):

```
def view(from: Int, until: Int): SeqView[A, Seq[A]]
```

you see that `SeqView[_, _]` actually has two type parameters, so it is not conforming to your specification `SEQ[e] <: GenSeq[e]`. (In theory you could imagine that if Scala supported partially-applied type constructors this could be unified somehow, but it is a tricky problem and Scala does not support it).

In your case, you can make it work by making a definition that is explicit for `SeqView` and does not use higher-kinded types:

```
implicit def SeqViewEquality[T](implicit equality: Equality[T]): Equality[SeqView[T, Seq[T]]] = new Equality[SeqView[T, Seq[T]]] {
  override def areEqual(self: SeqView[T, Seq[T]], b: Any): Boolean = b match {
    case other: GenSeq[_] => self.size == other.size && self.zip(other).forall(equality.areEqual _ tupled)
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Though, I admit this is somewhat unsatisfying.